# How to debug Javascript running in a webview on an iPad?

Tags: javascript, debugging, ipad, webview

I have an iPad running some Javascript in a webview, but sometimes it just refuses to work. Does anyone have a way to debug this kind of issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use bookmarklets to run things like firebug lite: Check the following article for links to how to make bookmarklets installable on mobile safari as well as links to firebug lite.
http://community.godaddy.com/library/setting-up-a-debugging-environment-on-the-ipad/

Answer (score 9):

Recently with the new iOS 6 you can turn on remote debugging and analyze your project with Webkit Inspector on Safari (but only with a Mac, because you must have safari 6.x).

This method would not work on the first generation of iPad too, because they're not upgradeable to iOS 6.

The question is one year old and obviously it wasn't available at the moment. I'm posting it so that someone who come up here could know it.

Info: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers

Answer (score 3):

Another tool you could try is [adobe shadow](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/).

Answer (score 1):

Simply [enable js console](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/14447/step-by-step-turn-on-the-iphone-ipads-web-debugging-console/)

Comment: This is the most useless debug console you could find anywhere.  If your error is an "undefined" error, you will get no file or line# information at all.  You will just know there there is an "undefined error" SOMEWHERE in your application.

Comment: @Josh: Yes I know, but sometimes it easiest way to debug

Comment: But it's these annoying "undefined" errors where you need a good console the most... so this is not a really good answer.

Comment: No longer available in iOS 7