# How can I enable Safari web inspector on WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have a hybrid application that uses the WKWebView to display large amounts of text and this in turn uses Javascript extensively to do text analysis. We're currently facing performance problems and I'd like to use the Safari Inspector the same way I used with the previous version of the application that uses the UIWebView. Problem is, I have enabled the Developer menu in Safari but I can't bind the web inspector on my iPad app.

Given that this used to work with the UIWebView, am I missing something new? Are there any other settings I need to fiddle with?

Comment: take a look to this; i think its almost the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335491/how-to-debug-javascript-running-in-a-webview-on-an-ipad

Comment: Not sure. This used to work with the UIWebView, it stopped because of the upgrade to WKWebView.

Comment: oh! so try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871586/how-to-debug-javascript-code-inside-a-wkwebview

Comment: Almost. Both Safari and WKWebView are no longer in beta.

Comment: wow, so i will follow this post. In a pair of months will be useful for me

Comment: What MacOS version do you have?

Comment: Latest. Hardware is from last year.

Comment: Strange. I was going to suggest that you need 10.10. I've got a [simple browser testbed](https://github.com/pavel-zdenek/nsurlprotocol-testbed). Tweaked it for `WKWebView` quickly and it WFM in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the application on the iPad via Xcode. This should whitelist it for inspection (during development only, of course).