# Run Firebug Lite from a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, firebug-lite

I'm trying to debug an iPad mini and don't have access to a Mac.

I need to log some events during page-load. Is there some way to activate Firebug Lite from the JavaScript file, so that it's available while initiation JavaScript is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to debug Javascript running in a webview on an iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335491/how-to-debug-javascript-running-)
in-a-webview-on-an-ipad

This SO answer covers this a little bit, but I think you want to look further into remote debugging.  See this tutorial here:

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/